# PHP MySQL insert error handling

Tags: php, mysql

Good day,

I need help with the following issues. I need to retrieve data from one table and insert into another table. The issues I'm having is with these two points:

1. script needs to continue from the last import in case of some failure
2. script should also detect whether another instance of the script is already in progress and exit

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_defined_functions());
echo "</pre>";*/

echo "testX";
try {
    $link = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

if (!$link)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
else
{
echo "link worked!";
}
mysql_select_db("aaatrycmpg_db2", $link);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  source_cdr");
//print_r($result);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>callstart</td><td>src</td><td>dst</td>                  <td>accountcode</td><td>uniqueid</td><td>ID</td><td>callanswer</td><td>callend</td> <td>disposition</td><td>cdr_id</td><td>pin_code</td><td>provider</td></tr>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo "<tr><td>".$row['callstart']."</td><td>".$row['src']."</td><td>".$row['dst']."    </td><td>".$row['accountcode']."</td><td>".$row['uniqueid']."</td><td>".$row['ID']."</td><td>".$row['callanswer']."</td><td>".$row['callend']."</td><td>".$row['disposition']."</td><td>".$row['cdr_id']."</td><td>".$row['pin_code']."</td><td>".$row['provider']."</td></tr></table>";
  $callstart = $row['callstart'];
  $callanswer = $row['callanswer'];
  $callend = $row['callend'];
  $datetime=$callstart; 
$date=substr($datetime, 0, 10); 
echo $date."<br>"; 
  $callduration = strtotime($callend) - strtotime($callstart);
  $talkduration = strtotime($callend) - strtotime($callanswer);
  echo strtotime($callend)." - ".strtotime($callstart)." = ".$callduration." = ".$talkduration;
  echo "<br />";
  if ($row['cdr_id'] != '1')
  {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO destination_cdr     (calldate,source,destination,account_code,pincode,duration_call,duration_talk,disposition,clid,cdr_id,provider)
VALUES ('".$callstart."','".$row['src']."','".$row['dst']."','".$row['accountcode']."','".$row['pin_code']."',".$callduration.",".$talkduration.",'".$row['disposition']."','".$row['ID']."','".$row['cdr_id']."','".$row['provider']."')");
  }
  }


?>
```

Comment: why do you want several instances to run at the same time?

Comment: do NOT use mysql_* functions, they are going to be deprecated any day now. Use PDO.

Comment: Or mysqli, which has a very similar syntax.

Comment: @Your Common Sense its just for testing purposes. Will comment out

Comment: @RichBradshaw how do you know? Do you use mysqli yourself?

Comment: I was really commented on wronisasty's comment, but yes, either PDO or mysqli depending on the project.

Answer (score 1):

1. you don't format your query parts properly.
2. you don't need PHP for this at all.

Just make it

```
INSERT INTO destination_cdr
(calldate,source,destination,account_code,pincode,duration_call,duration_talk,disposition,clid,cdr_id,provider) 
SELECT callstart,src, etc. FROM source_cdr
```

dates can be reformatted as well, using TO_DAYS() or similar mysql functions

I don't see much use in all that moving mess at all. Why not to just keep all records in the source_cdr?

Comment: Thanx, I will clean up my code before launching. I need to Insert into new table as the source_cdr table will actually be and SOAP import.